# View all login history on MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: mac, operating-systems, users

What command can I use in terminal to see login history? I think it's possible someone created a hidden account or booted the machine in safe mode.

Answer (score 25):

The venerable Unix utility for viewing previous logins is [`last`](https://ss64.com/osx/last.html).

See `man last`

Comment: This answer is correct and might show info, however if an attacker had physical access to an unlocked machine they can easily remove any evidence of their access. If you are concerned about such access you need to enable full disk encryption and always lock your screen.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me on Catalina, it shows wrong values.

Answer (score 24):

Checked on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5

```
sudo log show --style syslog  --last 1d | awk '/Enter/ && /unlockUIBecomesActive/ {print $1 " " $2}'
```

1d - is a shortcut for a period back in time

Comment: very slow, but works ^^

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I did it.

To see your login history on your Mac:

1. Open the "Terminal" app
2. Type the word [`last`](https://ss64.com/osx/last.html) followed by your username. For example, `last johnsmith`.
3. A list of login activity for your user account will appear in reverse chronological order.

For folks unfamiliar with Terminal:

To open, you can quickly find it in the Spotlight Search (hourglass search icon at top-right of screen).

The process I described worked today for me. I am using OS X Yosemite (10.10.5). I haven't tested it with other Mac operating systems.

Comment: Can we see it by month or days view, I see it but it shows a list of random logins